# Styling the < iOS3.2 movie player with black background

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

In iOS versions before 3.2, in which you have to use MPMoviePlayerController directly to play media, if you play an audio file you get the following styling:

[image]

I would like to get rid of the Quicktime graphic including all of the whitish grey colour that runs right to the bottom underneath the play/pause control, but without obscuring the play/pause control. This is easy enough in iOS3.2+ where you set the backgroundView property on MPMoviePlayerController colour to black -- but that technique isn't available for pre-iOS3.2.

Any ideas on how to do this? I know of a technique for overlaying something over the movie player view, but it would have to be a black mask with an rounded rectangle shaped hole in it in exactly the place where the play/pause control is -- that seems awfully fragile and fiddly.

Another technique might be to insert something into the UIView heirarchy at just the right place, but again this seems fragile and prone to break in future.

Comment: Good question but you are actually answering it to yourself already. Both of your options for a solution seem feasible. Chances of Apple ever again updating 3.0-systems are strongly and quickly tending towards zero. Just detect the runtime version and with anything prior to 3.2, select your hacky solution.

Comment: Yeah, think you're right Till. The overlaid rectangle it is then...

Comment: I'm giving up on the preiOS3.2 overlay idea -- had problems with the overlaid graphic having the wrong orientation -- I could try hacking round that but don't have time to end up down a rabbit hole...